# Zombie movie with evolving zombies - ability to run & speak

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

I'm looking for a *zombie apocalypse* movie (or show but I think it was a movie, not 100% sure).
It was spoken in English, I've seen it between the years 2000-2010. It didn't look too old so I would say it was made around 2006-ish.
It was in color. I'm not sure if it's an American movie or not, but I would go for it.

The movie is basically a zombie apocalypse, but the further you go into the movie, the more evolved the zombies get. 
At the start of the movie zombies could only just walk and not run. Later on they can run and speak. (There isn't much speaking by zombies in it of course, just maybe a few scenes)

**A scene I remember**:

> They (*a group of people*) are running in some kind of building (*might be a hospital*). Zombies are chasing them, running I might add. They enter a room and close the door behind them. They lock the door so they can't enter. There is a small window in the door which is broken. You can clearly hear the zombie sounds '*Grraaghhghggh*' but then one of the zombies looks through the small window on the door and starts to speak. I believe **the zombie** said something about 'we are evolving, now we are running and learning to speak, we will get you eventually'.
>   I think the woman shows a shocked face (due to the first speaking zombie and not sure if she says anything back), then the group of people just left.

This is the first scene in the movie where a zombie starts to speak I believe.
I think the main character is a woman with brown long hair.

**EDIT**: I think that there was something *'special'* about the zombies, their brain.

---

**UPDATE**: It's **NOT**:

- *Warm Bodies*
- *Land of the Dead*
- *One of the Resident Evil movies*
- *Dawn of the Dead*
- *Pontypool*
- *Day of the Dead*
- *28 Days Later*
- *28 Weeks Later*
- *Zombie Apocalyse*

**EDIT**: Seeing as *Warm Bodies* is from 2013, I believe the movie that I'm looking for is indeed older like from 2000-2008.

**EDIT**: It's a horror/thriller, not a comedy nor chick flick movie.

Comment: Maybe you could look through the [list of zombie films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zombie_films) and see if you recognize the title. You can sort it by the year of release by clicking on the column head.

Comment: @VedranŠego I've tried and looked up the trailers also. I couldn't find this specific scene anywhere yet.

Comment: @Decypher Um, there is absolutely *no* obligation to remove wrong answers, especially on ID questions where they can serve as confirmations for future answerers what movies are *not* looked for. Just to make it seem "unanswered" is *not* a valid reason at all, and as cde said, it's still unanswered if the answer has a score of 0. This might not stop you from asking the answerer to do something that he doesn't have to otherwise, but in the future please refrain from "not an answer" flagging posts that *actually answer the question*.

Comment: Do you remember any more details about the setting? Was it urban or some other area? Did it take place in the US? About how long into the apocalypse did it take for the zombies to speak? Days, months, years? And did the main character travel alone or in a group?

Comment: I mentioned that they travelled in a group. Anything else I don't remember.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, they're *kind of* zombies (They behave like ones, but the film insists they're mutant vampires). You seem to be looking for [Against the Dark](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1194271/combined) from 2009 with Steven Seagal.

> When most of the population of Earth is infected with a virus and transformed into **flesh eaters** and blood drinking creatures, a group of hunters led by Tao chases the vampire zombies to eliminate them. **Six non-infected survivors try to find the exit of an abandoned hospital** crowded with the infected creatures, and Tao and his group help them. Meanwhile, the military command is ready to bomb the area and wipe it from the map.

The scene you're after is below. After one of the 'vampires' chases a character, he then tells her this in a warped voice through a broken window in the door, triggering a shocked reaction:

> *What's the point of running anymore? Open the door. This nightmare can stop. Right here, right now. **One of us is going to get you.** Think! You've already given in. Us? **We think. We talk. We plan.** Come closer. I'll tell you a secret. Come closer. **We've evolved.** You people are just cattle to us.*

Here's the scene (the sound is a bit out of sync):

Comment: This is it! I thought it was a zombie movie but seemed to be mutant-vampire, totally remembered that wrong. But this is the scene indeed, the door with the small window, broken glass. First time he talks! Thanks so much, enjoy the bounty :)

Comment: Thanks! It was a very good question, sorry I only had time to look it up now. And BTW, to be fair, I think that even the *characters* argue that these are really zombies. Not a good sign when your own characters don't buy the premise of your film... ;)

Comment: hehe, no problem, may I ask how you found it/how you searched? Or did you just know the scene?

Comment: I don't remember, TBH. Possibly through the word 'evolve'. I think I just got lucky. [And I doubt I knew this scene... Unless it seeped into my subconscious when I was dozing off in front of the TV or something :D]

Comment: I favourited this question because the premise sounded interesting. But, 3.2 on IMDb looks beyond disappointing. Is it really that bad? Btw, the clip in the answer is "Warm Bodies" trailer.

Comment: *"Is it really that bad?"* It's a direct-to-video zombie-vampire Steven Seagal film, 15 years past his prime. Have a guess. ;) *"clip in the answer is "Warm Bodies" trailer"* Er, no it's not. That trailer is in a deleted answer, though.

Comment: @Walt Thanks. It took a force reload to finally get the right video to show. A weird glitch, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a movie called Zombi 3.

http://zombie.wikia.com/wiki/Intelligent_Zombies - 
(In the Italian horror film Zombi 3, people infected with the zombie virus posses the ability to speak and retain some of their old personality, but they become psychotic and crave human flesh)

Comment: Sorry, it seemed to be Against The Dark.

Answer (score -2):

"28 weeks later"?

It came out in '07, and stared Rose Byrne (a woman with long brown hair)

I don't remember if the zombies spoke, but they definitely ran; and I think they showed some ability to think/solve problems.

Comment: This isn't the movie either, neither 28 days later.

Answer (score -2):

I think the one you are searching for is, The Legend. Will Smith is the main protagonist, and the whole city has been affected by virus. He lives with a dog named Sam, and each day he goes outside in search of any survivors and when night comes he stays hidden inside his house quietly: as the zombies or whatever they are, are active on nighttime. And apparently, by luck he catches one of them on one day and conduct an experiment on it to it back to life. In the climax scene, the zombies invade his house and one of them speaks to Will by asking to give her back.

Comment: [I Am Legend](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_(film))

Comment: That's the one you should be searching for

Comment: no, we've already had this answer once. it's not I am Legend